# Shared folder accessible from all over the Internet

Tags: linux, samba, shared-folders

I want to create a shared folder on my Debian server and make it accessible from all over the Internet. I want to store some files in it that I want to be downloadable from everywhere.
No passwords, no users, just go, browse and download.

I also want it to be accessible from Windows, Mac and Linux hosts.

Comment: Why don't you just apply for a Dropbox account ? Same thing, much less hassle. Otherwise look into Owncloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [install the Apache server](https://wiki.debian.org/Apache), you will automatically have the possibility to put files in the web root under `/var/www` or any of its subfolders.

Normally, directory listings are enabled, so if you create a directory, say `/var/www/foo`, and have users browse to `http://example.com/foo`, then they will get a listing of all files in that directory.

Comment: And enable WebDAV so you can upload files directly from Windows Explorer etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can just set up [apache](https://wiki.debian.org/Apache) and create whatever you want. Set up your port forwarding. Without an index.html file a user will get a directory listing of whatever you have in there. Should be an easy enough way to set up what you want.

You can either browse to your external IP or purchase a domain name. Entirely up to you.

Comment: Ok thank you that's what I will do. I can only vote one answer as "accepted" but both of you were correct. Thanks again!